# Using JOLT convert List to Array of Objects

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I've spent quite a lot of time figuring it out but I'm stuck, I have a nested JSON and I want to enrich the values of "attr" with those matching the keys of "codes", thanks in advance.

My Input JSON:

```json
{
  "items": {
    "a1b2xxxx": {
      "name": "item 1",
      "attr": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
      ]
    },
    "c2b2cxxxx": {
      "name": "item 2",
      "attr": [
        "D",
        "E",
        "F"
      ]
    }
  },
  "codes": {
    "A": {
      "color": "green"
    },
    "B": {
      "size": "M"
    },
    "C": {
      "sku": "NS"
    },
    "D": {
      "stock": 2
    },
    "E": {
      "some_key": "some_value"
    },
    "F": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

My Desired Output JSON:

```json
{
  "items": {
    "a1b2xxxx": {
      "name": "item 1",
      "attr": {
        "A": {
          "color": "green"
        },
        "B": {
          "size": "M"
        },
        "C": {
          "sku": "NS"
        }
      }
    },
    "c2b2xxxx": {
      "name": "item 2",
      "attr": {
        "D": {
          "stock": 2
        },
        "E": {
          "some_key": "some_value"
        },
        "F": {
          "foo": "bar"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "codes": {
    "A": {
      "color": "green"
    },
    "B": {
      "size": "M"
    },
    "C": {
      "sku": "NS"
    },
    "D": {
      "stock": 2
    },
    "E": {
      "some_key": "some_value"
    },
    "F": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

My approach is following:

1. Using **cardinality** operation convert `attr` to an array of objects
2. Then maybe I can map values from codes using **modify-default-beta**

But I am stuck at step 1. Here is my transformer:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "attr": "ONE"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single **shift** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "name": "&2.&1.&",
          "attr": {
            "*": { // the level of the indexes of "attr" array, eg. 0,1,2
              "*": { // the level of the components of "attr" array, eg. A,B,C,D,E,F
                "@(5,codes.&)": "&5.&4.&" // going four levels up the tree to get the object labels of "a1b2xxxx" and "c2b2cxxxx"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "*": "&" // objects(attributes or array) other than "items", eg. "codes" 
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @barbaros. I am new to JOLT. Can you point me out where I learn more about it?

Comment: You're welcome @AbdulRehman . There are some good links such as [1](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases), [2](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt), [3](https://intercom.help/godigibee/en/articles/3159219-transformer-operations-overview), [4](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Jolt-quick-reference-for-Nifi-Jolt-Processors/ta-p/244350), [5](https://cool-cheng.blogspot.com/2019/12/json-jolt-tutorial.html). Have a nice study.

Answer (score 0):

Another spec can be like this:

You can use values of array with `@` and use them as key `@(0)` like `"@": "&4.&3.&2.@(0).color"`

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "items": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.&1.&",
          "attr": {
            "*": {
              "@": "&4.&3.&2.@(0).color"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```